# Вопрос по ip геолокации: определить город посетителей по ip

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Посоветуйте пожалуйста базы, для определения геолокации по ip.

Хочу определить локации посетителей по ip, желательно с точностью до города(по крайней мере по России). Из баз нашел 2: Sypex и MaxMind, потыкал на тех данных что я им скармливал вроде обе работают нормально.

Может кто уже сталкивался с такой задачей, и знает другие базы или работал с этими базами и есть какие-нибудь отзывы по ним или вообще, что можно почитать по этой теме?

Answer (score 0):

Работаю с API DaData.ru. Посмотрите [тут](https://dadata.ru/api/detect_address_by_ip/)